# Calculate partial derivative $f'_x, f'_y, f'_z$ where $f(x, y, z) = x^{\frac{y}{z}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Calculate partial derivative $f'_x, f'_y, f'_z$ where $f(x, y, z) = x^{\frac{y}{z}}.$

I know I need to use the chain rule but I'm confusing here for some reason ..

By [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx), the chain rule for $z = f(x, y), x = g(t), y = h(t)$ is:

> $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$

I tired to find partial derivatives using this formula but I confused ..

Can you please help me find $f'_x, f'_y, f'_z$? Exam tomorrow .. :\

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the chain rule ?

Comment: @V.Rossetto $f(x, y, z)$ is like $pow(x, frac(y, z)$. no?

Comment: Yes it is, but here $x$, $y$ and $z$ are _independent_, they do not depend on another variable like $t$ in you example.

Comment: @V.Rossetto What do you mean by "`independent`"?

Comment: Let us say that $x\in\mathbf{R}$, $y\in\mathbf R^+$ and $z\in\mathbf R^+$. They are independent because one can choose any value for $x$, $y$ or $z$ without knowing the values of the other two. The function $f$ depends on *three variables*. You would have to use the chain rule if $x$, $y$ and $z$ depended on another variable $t$ and if you wanted to compute the $t$-derivative of $t\mapsto f(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. But in this case you would also have to compute $f'_x$, $f'_y$ and $f'_z$ to get the result.

Comment: By the way, could you use a more human-readable acronym, please ?

Comment: @V.Rossetto If I knew English good, I would .. Anyway, I tried again without using the chain rule and you are right, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving the answer for $f'_x$  and hope you will understand how it should work for the other two.

So to compute $f'_x$, $x$ is the **variable** and you consider $y$ and $z$ as **constants**. It is therefore the usual power derivative and you have
$$ f'_x(x,y,z)=\frac yzx^{\frac yz-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Take the logarithms of both sides and compute your derivatives as usual.

I am sure you will easily continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

use the definition 
$$
x^\frac{y}{z}=e^{(\log x) \frac{y}{z}}=e^{ \frac{y \log x}{z}}
$$